# JQuery .css li:hover > a

Tags: jquery, css, hover, html-lists

I'm a newbie when it comes to JQuery. I'm trying to basically allow visitors to choose between two color themes on my site. When they click the link for the light theme, everything changes color as it's supposed to except for various elements in my navigation menu. Here is the JQuery:

```
function SolarColors (){
    $('html').css('background-color', '#839496');
    $('body').css('background-color', '#839496');
    $('#main-container').css('background-color', '#FDF6E3').css('color', '#586E75');
    $('#title-bar').css('background-color', '#073642').css('color', '#268BD2');
    $('#content').css('background-color', '#FDF6E3');
    $('#color-bar').css('background-color', '#FDF6E3');
    $('h2').css('color', '#DC322F');
    $('.drop_menu').css('background-color', '#93A1A1');
    $('.drop_menu li a').css('color', '#ffffff');
    $('.drop_menu > li:hover > a').css('color','#00ff00');
}
```

Everything changes color except for the last item in that list:

```
    $('.drop_menu > li:hover > a').css('color','#00ff00');
```

does not work.

Here is what I have in my HTML:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a.color[name='solar']").click(function(){
        SolarColors();
    });
    $("a.color[name='zen']").click(function(){
        ZenColors();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Could you show your html (.drop_menu exactly)? I think you should do $('.drop_menu li:hover a').css('color','#00ff00');

Comment: What element is '.drop_menu'? For your js to work it would have to be a `<ul>` or `<ol>` element. Post the HTML for that element for more help.

Comment: Can you share your html for the drop_menu?  Maybe make a fiddle?  More generally I would recommend setting/changing a class on the body element in javascript and havng all the CSS in the CSS (for both themes, but in the context of the right class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably rewrite it like this

```
$('.drop_menu li a').hover( function(e){
     $(this).css('color', 'yourcolor');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If all else fails

```
$('.drop_menu > li').hover( hoverOn, hoverOff );

function hoverOn() { $('.drop_menu > li> a').css('color','#00ff00'); }
function hoverOff() { $('.drop_menu > li> a').css('color','ffffff'); }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because :hover is a css pseudo selector. It's not really a DOM element. You have to use the .hover() handler, like so:

```
$('.drop_menu > li > a').hover(function(){
    $(this).css('color', '#00ff00')
});
```

Or, as somebody else suggested, simply change a class on the body element with all of your styles. Much easier that way.